# Pending edit notification icon change

Tags: feature-request, status-completed

With the recent addition of queueing edits from users without sufficient rep to edit questions, there is a new notification icon on the tool bar.  The background color of the notification area and the font color of the number of questions in the queue are nearly identical making it impossible to see.

[image]

Forgot to add:  Win7/IE8.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the fix will be in the next deployment.